# Intersection of a subgroup with a subset, and related sets of the same cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a subgroup of abelian group $B$ and let $C$ be some subset of $B$.  Let $C + C = \{ c + c' : c, c' \in C\}$ and let $r C = C + C + \dots + C (r \text{ times})$.

Suppose that $A \cap C$ is finite.  Then $r (A\cap C)$ is also finite for all $r \geq 1$.  This is obvious to me since we're performing an elementwise sum of a finite set.

Consider $2(A \cap C) = \{ a + a': a, a' \in A \cap C \}$.  Well, $a'' \in 2 (A \cap C) \iff a'' = a + a'$ for some $a, a' \in A\cap C$.

**Question.** Since the above is $\iff a'' - a = a'$ for some $a,a' \in A \cap C$, does it follow that $(A - C) \cap A \cap C$ has the same size as $2(A \cap C)$?

I'm having trouble seeing the logical steps required to prove that the two sets are indeed the same size.  Is there a trick we can use?

Comment: Is your question about why $r(A\cap C)$ is finite or just the special set with $r=2$? It seems like $A$ being a subgroup doesn’t matter to either question, so do these fit into a different bigger question? Anyways, for your question I’m a little skeptical about them being the same size because the decomposition $a’’=a+a’$ need not be unique , which is probably why you can’t come up with a nice map like sending $a’’$ to $a’$.

Comment: If you just want to prove that $r(A\cap C)$ is finite for each $r\ge 1$, you don’t need to know the actual cardinalities of the sets $r(A\cap C)$. If $S$ is any finite subset of $B$, and $r\in\Bbb Z^+$, there are only $|S|^r$ $r$-tuples $\langle s_1,\ldots,s_r\rangle$ of elements of $S$, so $|rS|\le|S|^r$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know that it's finite.  My real question is finding a nice set related to $2 (A \cap C)$ such that it has the same size or smaller than $2 (A\cap C)$.

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent: Okay, but that isn’t at all clear from your question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see now, rereading the question.  I made some edits.  Can you think of any such set?  I've been stuck on this problem for days. :)

Comment: I know that $2(A\cap C) \subset A \cap 2C$ but the reverse doesn't hold, so that's no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not follow.  For instance, let $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$, and $C=\{0,1\}$.  Then $2(A\cap C)=\{0,1,2\}$ has three elements whereas $(A-C)\cap A\cap C=\{0,1\}$ has two elements.